# C++ Issue with deleting item from linked list

Tags: c++, class, struct, makefile, linked-list

Previous issue resolved!

New issue: the code itself. I've been working on the code for a function to delete a selected item off a linked list, how many times it may appear. However, when I run that part of the program to try to delete a node, it'll just end the program. I know something's bound to be off but even looking at tutorials on this, I'm not quite grasping how to achieve this instruction. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [RESOLVED]

Function

```
void LinkedList::deleteItem(int _newItem)
{
if(isEmptyList())
    cout << "\t<ERROR> List is empty.\n";

else
{
    bool itemDelete = false;

    nodeType *q = first;

    while(q != NULL)
    {
        if(first->info == _newItem)
        {
            nodeType *p = first->link;
            first->link = p->link;
            delete p;
            --count;
            itemDelete = true;
        }

        if(q->link->info == _newItem)
        {
            nodeType *r = q;
            nodeType *p = q;
            r = r->link;
            p->link = r->link;
            delete r;
            --count;
            itemDelete = true;
        }

        q = q->link;
    }
    if(itemDelete == true)
        cout << "Item was deleted.";
    else
        cout << "Item was not found.";
}
```

}

Class and struct

```
    struct nodeType
    {
     int info;
     nodeType *link;
    };

    class LinkedList
    {
     public:
        void initializeList();
        bool isEmptyList();
        void printList();
        int findLength();
        void destroyList();
        int infoFirst();
        int infoLast();
        bool searchItem(int);
        void insertFront(int);
        void insertBack(int);
        void deleteItem(int);
        int calcTotal();
        int calcAvg();
        LinkedList();

    private:
        nodeType *first, *last, *newNode;
        int count; //adds or remove one whenever a node is added or removed
    };
```

Comment: Precisely the following messages: "cannot open output file (folder name).exe access denied", "Id returned 1 exit status", & "recipe for target (folder name).exe failed".

Comment: This error isn't caused by your code (not saying your code is good). It means the linker is unable to write to the executable file which could be caused by attempting to build your code while an earlier version is running. Make sure you terminate all running instances of your program before you rebuild it.

Comment: So to sum up: no, your code to remove a node is not correct, but that's not causing your linking error. You just don't have permission to write to the output file. When was the last time compilation was successful? Could be as Bessie suggested with the program running currently.

Comment: Well then, indeed it was. Hadn't noticed an earlier version was still running. Tis happens when I have too many things open. Thanks, Bessie!

Comment: What's not correct about it, John?

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your code is this line:

```
if(q->link->info == _newItem)
```

you are accessing the next link in your linked list but that next link may be nullptr:

```
if(q->link != nullptr && q->link->info == _newItem)
```

Before you access its member info you should first check to see if it is nullptr.

You should also consider moving:

```
        if(first->info == _newItem)
        {
            nodeType *p = first->link;
            first->link = p->link;
            delete p;
            --count;
            itemDelete = true;
        }
```

outside the loop because you will go through this check everytime that you enter the loop if the node that you are trying to remove is not the first one since you are checking the node first, instead of the node q which you are using to loop through your linked list.

Also please consider using nullptr instead of NULL.

```
else
{
    bool itemDelete = false;

    nodeType *q = first;

    if(first->info == _newItem)
    {
        nodeType *p = first->link;
        first->link = p->link;
        delete p;
        --count;
        itemDelete = true;
    }
// by doing !itemDelete you will exit once you find the item
// or you won't enter the loop if the item was the first in the list
    while(q != nullptr && !itemDelete)
    {
        if(q->link != nullptr && q->link->info == _newItem)
        {
            nodeType *r = q;
            nodeType *p = q;
            r = r->link;
            p->link = r->link;
            delete r;
            --count;
            itemDelete = true;
        }

        q = q->link;
    }
    if(itemDelete == true)
        cout << "Item was deleted.";
    else
        cout << "Item was not found.";
}
```

This portion here can be further collapsed:

```
// by doing !itemDelete you will exit once you find the item
while(q != nullptr && !itemDelete)
{
    if(q->link != nullptr && q->link->info == _newItem)
    {
        nodeType *r = q;
        nodeType *p = q;
        r = r->link;
        p->link = r->link;
        delete r;
        --count;
        itemDelete = true;
    }

    q = q->link;
}
```

to:

```
 // by doing !itemDelete you will exit once you find the item
    while(q->link != nullptr && !itemDelete)
    {
        if(q->link->info == _newItem)
        {
            nodeType *r = q;
            nodeType *p = q;
            r = r->link;
            p->link = r->link;
            delete r;
            --count;
            itemDelete = true;
        }

        q = q->link;
    }
```

I hope that this helps you.

Comment: Much appreciated!